# Refer to outer column in inner query Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Employee and Departament in relation that is shown bellow. For each departament I want to get the fifth best paid employee.

[image]

How the query should look like if we have for example MySQL?

I trying to do something like this but it doesn’t see d.id column in inner select.

```
select d.name, e.id from Employee e
join Departament d on d.id = e.dep_id
where e.id = (
    select s.eid from (
        select ee.id as eid, @rowid:=@rowid+1 as rowid from Employee ee, (SELECT @rowid:=0) as init
        where ee.dep_id = d.id
        order by ee.salary desc
     ) s
    where s.rowid = 5
)
```

Is it possible to do it in generic way not dependent to any database semantics?

How to do it using MySQL and what is the best way to do it?

Comment: The ANSI SQL way to get 5:th item is OFFSET/FETCH FIRST. But only a few dbms products support it this far. I don't know if MySQL is any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the `row_id` calculation in the `from` clause:

```
select d.name, e.id
from (select ee.*,
             (@rowid := if(@d = dept_id, @rowid + 1,
                           if(@d := dept_id, 1, 1)
                          )
             ) as rowid
      from Employee ee cross join
            (SELECT @rowid := 0, @d := NULL) as init
      order by ee.dept_id, ee.salary desc
     ) e join
     Departament d
     on d.id = e.dept_id
where e.rowid = 5;
```

And, yes, there is an ANSI standard way of doing this.  In fact, I can readily think of two approaches.  But MySQL supports neither window functions not `fetch first 1 row only`.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. It generates error "#1054 - Unknown column 'dept_id' in 'field list'".

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT X.NAME, X.SALARY AS SAL_5 FROM
     (
     SELECT DEPT.NAME,EMP.SALARY, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY SALARY DESC) RN
      FROM EMP, DEPT
     WHERE EMP.DEPT_ID=DEPT.DEPT_ID
     ) X
     WHERE X.RN=5;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Answers usually attract more attention and thus will get you more reputation if you provide some explanations with your example. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, "#1305 - FUNCTION RANK does not exist ".